# Underscore.js : iterate json object and check key availability using _.has()

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I am underscore.js newbie and I am trying to iterate through below JSON object and check, if certain fields exists. In this case, I need to bring out the records in all_rec best matching with input.

```
input = {first_name: "John", surname: "Paul", email: "john.paul@gmail.com"}

all_rec = [
    {"id": 1,"first_name": "John","surname": "Paul","email": "john.paul@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 2,"first_name": "Kerry","surname": "Morrison","phone": "43567823"},
    {"id": 3,"first_name": "John", "phone": "0345433234"}
]
```

I am expecting below records to be retrieved,

```
id : 1 ==> Matching all 3 fields ( firstname, surname  & email)
id : 3 ==> Matching only firstname (absence of surname & email)
```

I tried the following code,

```
let resultData = _.where(all_rec,  (
    (_.has(all_rec, "first_name") ? {first_name: input.first_name} : true) &&
    (_.has(all_rec, "surname") ? {surname: input.surname} : true) &&
    (_.has(all_rec, "email") ? {email: input.email} : true) &&
    (_.has(all_rec, "mobile") ? {mobile: input.mobile} : true)));
```

I expect it to bring out records with id: 1 & 3. But, it is bringing out all the records. Not sure as where I am going wrong.

Also, I am not sure, if this can be achieved using underscore.js. Kindly advise.

Comment: It's not clear how the record with `id: 3` is matched. In input you have `first_name: "John"` and in record with `id = 3` - `"first_name": "Sue"`, so how does it matched?

Comment: Sorry, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do it with `where`/`findWhere` function, but you definitely could achieve it using `filter`

Underscore Example:

```js
const input = {
  first_name: "John",
  surname: "Paul",
  email: "john.paul@gmail.com"
};

const all_rec = [
    {"id": 1,"first_name": "John","surname": "Paul","email": "john.paul@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 2,"first_name": "Kerry","surname": "Morrison","phone": "43567823"},
    {"id": 3,"first_name": "John", "phone": "0345433234"}
];

const resultData = _.filter(all_rec, item => 
  _.keys(item).every(key => _.has(input, key) ? input[key] === item[key] : true));

console.log(resultData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Vanilla ES6 Example:

```js
const input = {
  first_name: "John",
  surname: "Paul",
  email: "john.paul@gmail.com"
};

const all_rec = [
    {"id": 1,"first_name": "John","surname": "Paul","email": "john.paul@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 2,"first_name": "Kerry","surname": "Morrison","phone": "43567823"},
    {"id": 3,"first_name": "John", "phone": "0345433234"}
];

const resultData = all_rec.filter(item => 
  Object.keys(item).every(key => input.hasOwnProperty(key) ? input[key] === item[key] : true));

console.log(resultData);
```

Comment: Ihor, _.filter worked. Thank you very much, Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Function below implements _.has and will return match based on properties on input, and those available records.

```
input = {first_name: "John", surname: "Paul", email: "john.paul@gmail.com"}

all_rec = [
    {"id": 1,"first_name": "John","surname": "Paul","email": "john.paul@gmail.com"},
    {"id": 2,"first_name": "Kerry","surname": "Morrison","phone": "43567823"},
    {"id": 3,"first_name": "Sue", "phone": "0345433234"}
]

const matcher = (input, all_records) => {
    return all_records.filter(record => {
        const keysToUse = Object.keys(record).filter(key => _.has(input, key));
        if (keysToUse.length === 0) return false;
        return keysToUse.every(key => input[key] === record[key]);
    })
}

console.log(matcher(input, all_rec));
```

Comment: Greg, Thanks a lot :-)